# Sharing records with Customer Community Login users

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-rule, sharing-sets

I am struggling to get the concept of sharing rules vs sharing sets when it comes to sharing records owned by an internal user to a **community user** which has a license of **Customer Community Login User**.

Current Scenario:

- Custom Object - My_Object__c
- Owner - Internal User
- Target shared with Community portal users
- Sharing rules setup on My_Object__c: All internal users records shared with All Customer Portal Users

My question is, why is it if I use sharing rules, the data doesn't show in community for the users. And if I use sharing sets, it displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Customer Community license doesn't support advanced sharing. Ref (at the bottom of [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) document).

Advanced sharing is things like User-based, Criteria-base sharing territories and more. Your only option is a sharing set for this user license.

Given you want everyone to be able to see ALL records, have you considered making the org-wide-defaults for the object public read-only?

Comment: Hi Caspar! I guess sharing set is the way to go. I appreciate the explanation. I understand it now thanks to this document. Yes we have considered making it to public read-only but there was a requirement from client for the internal users to make it restrictive.